# How would fierce competition affect the adoption of alternative energy sources?

Tags: technological-development, energy, transportation, corporations

This is a continuation of the question asked here: [How long would it take for nuclear energy to become adopted in a world on the brink of collapse?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/136186/how-long-would-it-take-for-nuclear-energy-to-become-adopted-in-a-world-on-the-br)

So, with my current timeline, nuclear energy (and ZenCorp, the corporation behind it) has a headstart of 8-9 years before other alternatives come along. According to one of the answers, this should be enough time to see some changes in things like carts and buses.

But... then a new challenger approaches: another corporation begins pushing for other energy sources, such as solar, hydroelectric and tidal power, an alternative to ZenCorp's "nuclear solution".

### Things to take into consideration:

- The corporations are actively trying to undermine each other, like in the "nuclear solution" example above, meant to spread fear and unwillingness to adopt the competition's solutions.
- There's a constant state of flux across the world. Places that were relatively peaceful/safe a few weeks/months ago may not be so anymore. The flipside is also true: places that were being torn apart by war may reach a tense truce or one faction may ultimately rise victorious. Which leads us to...
- They are willing and able to set up shop in places were riots and crime are widespread (their security forces are essentially private armies), but wouldn't (knowingly and willingly) go into an active warzone.
- Despite their main clients being governments, the corporations have no qualms about working with those that overthrow them, so long as the feeling is mutual.
- Despite their militarized security forces, they don't engage in open armed conflict with each other. They're not above underhanded methods, such as sabotage or industrial espionage, though. If the agents sent on these missions are caught, well... they're far away from the public eye, so they'll mysteriously go missing or show up the day after as tragic victims of crime.

This leads to a situation in which one or another corporation holds the most *power* in a given area, even if the other eventually tries to expand there. This would be decided by the first one to strike a deal or whose propaganda was best internalized by the government/population.

So, considering the information above, how would this not-so-friendly competition (and the unstable state of the world) affect the adoption of their products and services, particularly the implementation of alternative energy sources?

Comment: With current dynamics in place (power stations take years to build and decades to pay off), this will be a very slow moving process.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander! There's a solution to the power stations taking years to be built (they would still take a while, though), but the "decades to pay off" does make me wonder. Could you tell me a little more about this, or point me in the right direction to investigate further?

Comment: I apologize, but what rule of your world are you asking about?  We build worlds here, not stories.  The actions of two corporations is entirely story-based.  A worldbuilding question about corporations would be a rule that would apply to all corporations - not just one or two. VTC OT:TSB.

Comment: Hi, @JBH! Thank you for your clarification! My question is geared towards the reaction of the world to said corporations (adoption of their products and services), rather than their actions. I can write their actions, but I'm unsure as to how that would affect the world they inhabit. Should I post this in the Writing Stack Exchange, then?

Comment: @Cuervo77 One suggestion I might make is to do some research into the War of the Currents. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_currents

Comment: OK, to avoid being too broad you need to explain (a) the specific action or consequence of the corporate infighting and (b) which specific segment of society that will react to it.  You can't ask for the whole world, that's too broad.  You really can't even ask for a nation's response as that's too broad.  I'm concerned that the question may be intrinsically subjective.  How an individual would react to a specific set of marketing initiatives is why entire colleges exist.  But what really has me concerned is that you have not defined the specific consequence.  (\*continued\*)

Comment: You state, `This should lead to a situation....` In other words, you don't know what the situation is that people are reacting to.  You're asking us to help define that situation, and that's too story-based.  You need to figure out the result of the infighting: what was the collateral damage?  Who came out on top?  etc.  Then you need to tell us about the community/society in question.  Then we can help you determine how your culture will react to the change.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean now! I wrote that paragraph in a way that was open to commentary, despite not being the main question. I've edited it to correct this. I do agree that even then, the question is too broad. I think I can find some of the answers I'm looking for in the War of the Currents, but I'll have to adapt what I learn from it from place to place.

Comment: The classic problem with nefarious mega-corporation intrigue is that there seems no reason for employees and executives to be loyal. After all, if they lie, cheat, and steal at every opportunity, then the promise of retirement and pension is just another lie. Folks see through such disloyalty from their employer quickly, and are disloyal in return. The mega-corporation won't remain mega for long..

Comment: Ah, that's actually something I explore in the story! While backhanded dealings do exist within corporations (within all factions, actually), most of the nastiness is directed at the opponents. You got it right, though: none of the mega-corporations remain mega for long; just not due to disloyalty.